# Url not hitting MVC attribute based routing controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using Attribute based routing in a MVC application. My Code is -

```
[RouteArea("MasterData")]
[RoutePrefix("BrandFacilityShipmentMaintenance")]
public class BrandFacilityShipmentMaintenanceController : Controller
{
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

    }
}
```

I am trying to hit the url with variabale parameters like

```
/MasterData/BrandFacilityShipmentMaintenance/Index
/MasterData/BrandFacilityShipmentMaintenance/Index/1156?pid=1120
/MasterData/BrandFacilityShipmentMaintenance/Index/1156?pid=1120&fname=Brand+Facility+Shipment+Maintenanca
/MasterData/BrandFacilityShipmentMaintenance/Index/1156?pid=1120&fname=Brand+Facility+Shipment+Maintenanca&isReffered=false
```

But it says resource not found. These all urls hit same Index action in Conventional based routing. What should I change to make it work in attribute based routing.

AreaRegistration.cs -

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    context.MapRoute(
        "Masterdata_default",
        "Masterdata/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: post your RouteConfig code for better clarity

Comment: @MannanBahelim posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url parameters are mapped to the method's parameters, sou you need to specify them in your method's signature.

```
public string Index(int id, int? pid)  { ... }
```

From [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/pass-parameter-or-query-string-in-action-method-in-Asp-Net-m/)

EDIT:
You can also access your query string parameters this way:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{ 
    string param1 = this.Request.QueryString["pid"];
    // parse int or whatever
}
```

EDIT2: [This](https://exceptionnotfound.net/attribute-routing-vs-convention-routing/) is also a good reading

Answer (score 0):

You are probably combining convention based routing with attribute routing, and you should register your areas after you map the attribute routes.

Add the area registration in `Application_Start()` after `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)`

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

Try to use the named parameter "AreaPrefix" in RouteArea

```
[RouteArea("MasterData", AreaPrefix = "MasterData")]
```

It should work.

Also you can remove the RouteArea attribute and use only RoutePrefix in following way

```
[RoutePrefix("MasterData/BrandFacilityShipmentMaintenance")]
```

Comment: I didn't see AreaPrefix in your code so suggested that. Try adding AreaPrefix in RouteArea